# Confusion regarding contour integral solution

Tags: contour-integration

In Schaum's complex variable book, there is an exercise in contour integration:
$$
\int \overline{z}^{2} dz
$$
over $|z|=1$.

The answer seems to be $0$, but when I integrate like this using contour integration formula, 
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-2i\theta} i e^{i\theta} d\theta
$$
$$
-e^{-2i\pi}.
$$
Then I get $-1$ as a result. :(

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're forgetting to evaluate at *both* endpoints. Note $e^0 \not= 0$.

Comment: Thank you @KCD, so silly of me. That was the problem, I was assuming it 0 instead of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-2i\theta}\,i\,e^{i\theta}\,d\theta=i\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-i\theta}\,d\theta=i\,\frac{e^{-i\theta}}{-i}\,\Bigr|_0^{2\pi}=0.
$$

Comment: I didn't understood the part before 0, shouldn't i and -i become -1 and after applying the limit and doing Euler's, we get 1. Finally 1 * -1 = -1? Sorry, if my question seems naive, I am just learning it.

Comment: $e^{-2\pi i}-e^0=1-1=0$.